# Is there a trick to emboss a textview (after api 25)

Tags: android, textview, emboss

Since Google annouced that the EmbossMaskFilter is deprecated, i was unable (even here) to find a way to emboss a textview. I saw that someone use canvas but i didn't really understand. So help appreciated to how emboss a textview.

Answer (score -1):

try to use 'elevation' property of textview and check .

Comment: An elevation add outer shadow, emboss is more like inner shadow (not really but only on a side) so i don't understand how i can emboss a textview with "elevation" ?
Can you clarify?